# SpringJPA bidirectional relationship - can't delete entiy

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am building my own project and I ran into an issue I somehow can't solve. When I remove, for example, Company, I also can see it in database. My test case passes successfully.

But the issue is, when I want to delete Ticket, it just doesn't get deleted. The only case it gets deleted is when I use fooRepository.deleteAll();

**User**

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"username"})})
public class User {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Size(min = 3, max = 32)
private String username;

@Size(max = 256)
private String password;

@Size(min = 3, max = 32)
private String firstName;

@Size(min = 3, max = 32)
private String lastName;

@Size(min = 5, max = 64)
private String email;

@JsonIgnoreProperties("user")
@OneToMany(
        fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
        mappedBy = "user",
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
        orphanRemoval = true
)
private List<Ticket> tickets;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
@JoinColumn(
        name = "role_id",
        insertable = false,
        updatable = false,
        columnDefinition = "INT DEFAULT 1"
)
private Role role;

@Column(columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
private Timestamp timeRegistered;
}
```

**Ticket**

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "ticket")
public class Ticket {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@JsonIgnoreProperties("tickets")
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
private User user;

@JsonIgnoreProperties("ticket")
@OneToMany(
        fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
        mappedBy = "ticket",
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
        orphanRemoval = true
)
private List<TicketItem> ticketItems;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "company_id")
private Company company;

@Column(
        columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP",
        insertable = false,
        updatable = false
)
private Timestamp timeCreated;

}
```

**TicketItem**

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "ticket_item", uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"price_id"})})
public class TicketItem {

@EmbeddedId
private TicketItemPk id;

@JsonIgnoreProperties("ticketItems")
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
@JoinColumn(
        name = "ticket_id",
        insertable = false,
        updatable = false
)
private Ticket ticket;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
@JoinColumn(
        name = "item_id",
        insertable = false,
        updatable = false
)
private Item item;

@Positive
@Column(name = "item_count")
private Integer count;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "price_id")
private Price price;
}
```

**Company**

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "company", uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"name"})})
public class Company {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Size(min = 1, max = 64)
private String name;
}
```

**Item**

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "item", uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"name"})})
public class Item {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;


@Size(min = 2, max = 64)
private String name;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
@JoinColumn(
        name = "type_id",
        insertable = false,
        updatable = false
)
private ItemType type;
}
```

Maybe showing the unit test will help, so I will post it here. I will also post here application.test-properties.

**application.test-properties**

```
spring.application.name=Homeconomy Testing Application
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/homeconomy_testdb?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&useSSL=false&useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=****
spring.datasource.password=****
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.open-in-view=false
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.output.ansi.enabled=ALWAYS
server.port=8080
```

**TestConfig**

```
@Ignore
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = HEcoAppBoot.class)
public abstract class TestConfig {

}
```

**RepositoryTestConfig**

```
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
public abstract class RepositoryTestConfig extends TestConfig {

}
```

**TicketRepositoryTest**

```
public class TicketRepositoryTest extends RepositoryTestConfig {

@Autowired
private TicketRepository repository;

@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;

@Autowired
private CompanyRepository companyRepository;

@Test
public void CRUD() {
    User user = userRepository.findAll().get(0);

    Company company = new Company();
    company.setName("TEST TICKET COMPANY");

    companyRepository.saveAndFlush(company);

    company = companyRepository.findByName(company.getName());

    List<Ticket> tickets = repository.findAll();

    Ticket insertTicket = new Ticket();
    insertTicket.setUser(user);
    insertTicket.setCompany(company);

    repository.saveAndFlush(insertTicket);

    List<Ticket> ticketsAfterInsert = repository.findAll();

    Ticket ticket = ticketsAfterInsert.get(ticketsAfterInsert.size() - 1);

    assertThat(ticket).isNotNull();
    assertThat(ticketsAfterInsert.size()).isGreaterThan(tickets.size());

    repository.deleteAll(ticketsAfterInsert);
    repository.flush();

    List<Ticket> ticketsAfterDelete = repository.findAll();

    assertThat(ticketsAfterInsert.size()).isGreaterThan(ticketsAfterDelete.size());
}
}
```

The part of my test which is failing is

```
assertThat(ticketsAfterInsert.size()).isGreaterThan(ticketsAfterDelete.size());
```

which is because of objects not being deleted from database. If anything is wrong with my question, please let me know. I will be glad for every help. I really tried many solutions I found here or elsewhere, but nothing just worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Apparently the User entity, which is the parent of the Ticket entity, shouldn't be annotated with CascadeType.ALL, only CascadeType.REMOVE.